# HTML CSS DIV Panels

Tags: html, css, panel

I want to make something like this:
[image]

What I do so far:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I achieve this...

Thanks! In Advance...

### See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SanaBukhari/DAFW9/)

---

Code Is As Follows:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="panel panel1">Panel 1x</div>
<div class="panel panel1">Panel 1x</div>
<br>
<div class="panel panel2">Panel 2x</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
    background: #eeeeee;
}
.panel {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ffffff;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 5px #C9C9C9;
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px 5x #C9C9C9;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px 5px #C9C9C9;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.panel1 {
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.panel2 {
    min-width: 245px;
    width: 245px;
}
```

Comment: Divs cannot wrap around like that. You can make **content** wrap around a floated object but all HTML elements are rectangular (at least for now).

Comment: Can you give me an example???

Comment: content wrap around a floated object @Paulie_D

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4f8p5/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/4f8p5/3/

Comment: Thanks! Is that possible with bootstrap panel?

Comment: If you want to float anything in a div (which is what a 'panel' is I assume) you can (mostly) but it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Alot! http://jsfiddle.net/SanaBukhari/DAFW9/19/ @Paulie_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the height of the div to the right smaller than the left one, and have no margin on top/bottom. This would produce the result you are looking for

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffff;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.panel1 {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.small {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 111px;
  height: 90px;
  min-height: 90px;
}
.panel2 {
  min-width: 245px;
  width: 245px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel1">Panel 1x</div>
<div class="panel panel1 small">Panel 1x</div>
<br>
<div class="panel panel2">Panel 2x</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, But I can't understand. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

See: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faisalawanlive/DAFW9/18/)

Hope you fix this problem:

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffff;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.panel1 {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
}
.panel2 {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.panel3 {
  min-width: 245px;
  width: 245px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel1">Panel 1x</div>
<div class="panel panel2">Panel 1x</div>
<br>
<div class="panel panel3">Panel 2x</div>
```

Comment: [That](http://jsfiddle.net/SanaBukhari/DAFW9/19/)'s Look some pretty. But Now the problem is shadow!!! ???

Comment: Yeah just came to say that. 
The problem is shadows will overlap whichever element is behind. Trying to put them on the same z-index level won't solve the problem either, since the browser will simply treat the latest element as being on top even if they're on the same level.

You can solve that by adding a white rectangle with :before. Here is an update to his solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/DAFW9/21/

Comment: Good answer from @Ege

Comment: Thanks @Ege I not see your comment before posting comment

Comment: Sana Please follow this link jsfiddle.net/DAFW9/21

Comment: Thanks Faisal Awan and @Ege. Originally that was for Bootstrap. But I will do it myself. Thanks Again.

Comment: @Ege - there is no room for any text in your panels

Answer (score 0):

Use a grid like https://simplegrid.io/ it is much better to use a grid system than spend your life fiddling with CSS, especially considering that whatever code you come up with might break in the future.