# How to create a panel in HTML

Tags: css, html

So I started learning HTML recently, and want to create my own website. I have changed the colour of the backgrounds, and giving it simple functions. I now want to create a simple panel that can house more functions on top of it, whilst keeping the background. I want something like the JPane in Java. Is it possible? Or am I better off just creating a website on Wix?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Right now your question is off topic as too broad and you will get better answers and less downvotes if your show effort and code. You likely just want a styled DIV using css

Comment: I will. Thank you. I will now close this question, and resubmit a better one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364626/html-css-div-panels - look at the comments: http://jsfiddle.net/DAFW9/21/

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. This explains what I am looking for. If only this popped up when I was searching earlier :D

Comment: I see now there is little room in those panels for text. I guess that can be the topic of your new question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap to create panel

```
      <div class="panel panel-primary" style="border: 2px solid blue">
        <div class="panel-header">
        //header Goes here 
    </div>
<div class="panel-body">
//Body here 
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">\
//footer
</div>
</div>
```

If you're not looking for this please let me know.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what Im looking for! Thank you!